# Exercises for the math of 3D software renderer

Tags: renderer

I wish to implement a 3D **software** renderer,
so I started to read "Tricks of the 3D Game Programming Gurus Advanced 3D Graphics and Rasterization".

The first chapters are pretty straight forward, but my problem is that
when he started with the math (Chp 4) I lost direction - he throws a lot of material (and I really bad with math), and there are no exercises which I can work on.

In exercises I mean writing some code, so I could see how each separate subject fits the whole image - for example, some exercises about polar coord's, other in vectors and so on...

From simple math books, I don't understand a thing - writing code
using a feature will make it more clear and understandable to me.

Is there is a website or a book which gives such exercises, or even suggestion to other book on the subject?

Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you started writing a software renderer? Can you render a triangle in space?

Comment: The only thing I did is putting pixel in 2d Cartesian System...

Comment: I am noob at this field

Comment: We all start as noob. What tutorial have you read beside a book that has "Advanced" in the title? Have you googled "DirectX Tutorial" or "Renderer c# tutorial" or any combination you would like?

Comment: I looked at a lot of books, this one is really for beginners, it's just the lack of exercises which bothers me.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you should start by http://slimdx.org/tutorials.php

It's the basic, and after that it's only a matter of building on top of it.